# Django registration constraint fails

Tags: python, django, validation, registration

I am using Django-registration and want to enforce unique emails on registration so I have:

```
url(r'^register/$', 'registration.views.register',
{'form_class':RegistrationFormUniqueEmail,
    'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend' }, name='registration_register'),
```

However, this is not working. I have fiddled around, for example in /registration/forms.py putting the validation code from `RegistrationFormUniqueEmail` into

`class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):`

which does indeed run the uniqueness constraint. I also put break points `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` into the separate method code for `RegistrationFormUniqueEmail` to ensure it was actually being called. Dependent on where I put the breakpoints, the code broke in the console, so it seems it was being run, but no validation is made.

I want a fix which doesn't involve me reshuffling the registration code in the source i.e. putting the unique email validation into the main form.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually forked `django-registration` and added the unique email validator directly into the default registration form in the package's `forms.py`. I did it at the package level because I wasn't able to successfully sub-class the default form anywhere else so it had to be in the package and I'm using pip dependencies to deploy on Heroku so have to pull the customised package.